# Trigger custom powershell scripts using azure xplat-cli module

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, azure-xplat-cli

I am using ansible hosted on linux to manage both Linux and windows VMs hosted on azure, and use azure xplat-cli commandline to create VMs. When i create windows server 2008, I need to trigger few startup scripts so that those are preconfigured while windows server is up. I was able to install CustomScript extension using below command

## azure vm extension set

I have uploaded my scripts to azure blob storage account, and i need to trigger scripts using the extension, and i don't find any proper documentation (documentation was only for powershell). Can you please help